# How does PDO parameter type binding affect query performance?

Tags: php, pdo

Essentially, what is the difference between:

```
$sth = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `foo` SET `bar` = :bar");
$sth->bindValue(':bar', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
```

and

```
$sth = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `foo` SET `bar` = :bar");
$sth->bindValue(':bar', 1);
$sth->execute();
```

Where `bar` is known to be an integer.

- Does MySQL engine use this information at any time?
- Is this only used when PDO statements are emulated?

Answer (score 0):

Just like with regular query, the type doesn't really matter as long as you're binding your numbers as strings - not the contrary.

Answer (score 0):

When you measure it (which you will do right now because I suggest doing so), you will notice barely no difference, because the time-consuming operation is the execution of the query itself, not the calling of a function with one more parameter and subsequent different handling of the value.